# Name of these parts in CoQ10?

Tags: biochemistry

Am giving presentation over Coenzyme Q10 Wednesday for my final project, but we haven't studied any biochem this year.  So questions have arisen.

CoQ10 has a Quinone head, an isoprenyl tail, and these additional oxygens on the left and three methyl groups not a part of the Quinone head or tail.

Is there a name for these two oxygens and three methyl groups?  Or a category?  Like the benzene ring and two oxygens is the Quinone head, what are the additional oxygens and methyl groups called, if anything?

CoQ10 diagram: http://www.mysupplementstore.com/media/wysiwyg/structure-of-CoQ10.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The additional groups are referred as methyl and methoxy groups. There is no category for these groups. It appears that the methoxy groups stabilizes the [intermediates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquinol#Molecular_aspects) of the oxidation or reduction reactions.